# DSolve Command - Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, dsolve

I want to solve this differential equation using Mathematica:

```
de[r_]= [(-6 r+(-7+θ) ρ[r] (ρ^′)[r]) (1+(ρ^′)[r]^2)+r ρ[r] (ρ^′′)[r]
DSolve[de[r_]==0,r,ρ[r]]
```

which is not working.
is there other way to solve this?

Comment: This `de[r_]:=((-7+θ)ρ[r] ρ'[r])(1+ρ'[r]^2)+r ρ[r] ρ''[r]; DSolve[de[r]==0,ρ[r],r]` solves instantly. Adding the -6r in front seems to stun it. If you could provide initial conditions this might help. If you could also assign a constant numeric value to θ then you would be able to try using `NDSolve`.

Comment: you really need to take some time to learn the basic syntax. Square brackets are not used for grouping in mathematica. What is `p^''`, supposed to be??

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there another way to solving the differential equation  without changing it?

Comment: Make sure your input is exactly correct and then let MMA grind on it for a few weeks on a computer with LOTS of memory and see if it ever finds a solution. I do not know if there is any closed form solution or any MMA can ever find. You might try a series solution like this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/solving-an-ode-in-power-series using something like this odeOperator = ((-7+ϑ) # D[#,r])(1+D[#,r]^2)+r # D[#,{r,2}]&; xx=Series[ρ[r], {r,0,3}];
soln = Simplify[SolveAlways[odeOperator[ xx]==0,t]] I do not know if that will work without any initial conditions.